# PlatformNavBar doesn't respect BottomNavigationBarType.fixed material property

Tags: flutter, dart, multiplatform

I'm using `flutter_platform_widgets: ^3.2.0` to achieve platform specific ui in my flutter app. Howvever `PlatformNavBar` widget from the said class doesn't seem to respect `BottomNavigationBarType.fixed` material property properly. As in the label size increases when a tab is selected. This is my implementation.

```
return PlatformScaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  body: IndexedStack(
    // saves state
    index: currentIndex,
    children: screens,
  ),
  bottomNavBar: PlatformNavBar(
      currentIndex: currentIndex,
      itemChanged: (index) => setState(() => currentIndex = index),
      material: (context, platform) {
        return MaterialNavBarData(
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed, 
        );
      },
```

Is there anyone else who faced this issue? Did you find a workaround?